# Springboot Junit At least one SecurityBuilder<? extends SecurityFilterChain> needs to be specified error

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

Springboot 2.5.13 (with security on), Junit5:

Error: At least one SecurityBuilder<? extends SecurityFilterChain> needs to be specified. Typically this is done by exposing a SecurityFilterChain bean or by adding a @Configuration that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. More advanced users can invoke WebSecurity.addSecurityFilterChainBuilder directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Disable security: in /tests folder, create a @Configuration for the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to allow all the requests:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
  }
}
```