# I am unable to get my controller test to work

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am writing tests for a springboot application, and my class that tests controller always fails with this error. I have tried auto wiring and mocking `springSecurityFilterChain` but I still end up getting the exception.

*Exception*
`Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one SecurityBuilder<? extends SecurityFilterChain> needs to be specified. Typically this is done by exposing a SecurityFilterChain bean or by adding a @Configuration that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. More advanced users can invoke WebSecurity.addSecurityFilterChainBuilder directly`

I have a security config class that has a custom authentication  filter which looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /*
         * Setting custom login endpoint
         * */
        CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
        customAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/login/**", "/api/token/refresh/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/save/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/daraja/register-url/validation/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/daraja/register-url/confirmation/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and();

        http.addFilter(customAuthenticationFilter);
        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

I also have a custom authorisation filer class:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private UserService userService;
    private final MessageSource messageSource = null;

    public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String phoneNumber = request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(phoneNumber, password);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        // TODO move "secret" to secure location
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());

        String accessToken = JWT.create().withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 60 * 1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sign(algorithm);

        String refreshToken = JWT.create().withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 300 * 60 * 1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sign(algorithm);

        Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
        tokens.put("access_token", accessToken);
        tokens.put("refresh_token", refreshToken);

        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), tokens);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
        error.put("error", messageSource.getMessage(MessageUtil.ERROR_USER_ALREADY_EXISTS, null, Locale.ENGLISH));

        // response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        // new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);
        // TODO: enrich/improve error messages
        response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        response.getWriter().write("{\"error\": \"authentication error?\"}");
    }

}
```

the controller under test:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("")
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CAN_VIEW_ALL_PLATFORM_MEMBERS')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userService.getUsers());
    }
}
```

The test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {
    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @MockBean
    private SecurityConfig securityConfig;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityBuilder securityBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "254704760842", roles = {"PLATFORM_SUPER_ADMIN"})
    @DisplayName("Should list all users GET: /api/users/")
    void shouldGetUsers() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/"))
                .andExpect(status().is(200))
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
    }
}
```

What should I do to get the test working?

Comment: Just a note that when you come to write real world code, please don't log passwords.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Lousy oversight on my part

Comment: Please check whether this is helpful for you or not
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72315307/springboot-junit-at-least-one-securitybuilder-extends-securityfilterchain-nee